# How to remove a css class and close a pop up message at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm modifying a memory game ([originally in this repo](https://github.com/saelsa/memory-card-game)) which shows a pop up message with the game results once the game is completed:

[image]

When the pop up message is introduced, the rest of the screen is assigned a "game-over" css class that darkens the screen (behind the pop up).

```
//function for what happens when all pairs are found and the game is over


 function gameOver() {
        stopWatch();

        $('.container').addClass('animated rotateIn');

        messageWinning();
    }

//function for the popup message on winning
function messageWinning() {

    $(`<section class="game-over"><div class="message-box" > <h2>Yay! You have found all pairs!</h2><p>Number of attempts: ${attempts}</p><p>Time required: ${showMinutes}:${showSeconds} </p><p>Level: ${stars} </p><p><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></p></section>`).insertAfter($('.game'));

    $('.message-box').fadeIn(1);

}
```

How can I add some js that will let me to close the pop up message AND at the same time remove the "game-over" class, so the user can see their cards once they have completed the game?

**What I've done so far but hasn't worked:**

I added the following code to the js file to remove the "game-over" class but this never worked. I also tried it without the parent() variation but still no results.

```
$('.message-box').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().removeClass('game-over');
        });
```

Comment: So add something to click and remove the element?

Comment: Popup will close if you click an arrow

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, I did try that but what I did didn't work (I've edited the question to show what I've tried)

Comment: @Smollet777 don't know which arrows you mean? The keyboard ones?

Comment: @Bhautik I've updated the question to show one of the steps I followed that didn't work, hope this is what you meant with your comment

Comment: Check my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `<div class="close-popup">` to inside `message-box` popup.

```
<div class="close-popup">Close</div>
```

Add below CSS to place the close top of the right side of the popup.

```
.message-box {
    position: relative;
}

.close-popup {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

On click of close hide `.message-box` and remove `.game-over` class from a parent.

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-popup', function() {
    $('.message-box').hide().parent().removeClass('game-over');
    createBoard();
});
```

**Check below snippet**

```js
$(function() {

  //DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
  const memoryBoard = $('#memory-game');

  //array that holds the values for the memory cards
  let cardArray = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H'];
  let comparisonArray = [];

  //
  let attempts = 0; //counts how many attempts a player has made
  let stars = '<i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i>'; //stores the stars to display
  let clickCount = 0; //counts if this is the first click in an attempt
  let pairs = 0; //counts how many pairs have already been discovered
  let cardID = ''; //stores the card ID of solved pairs


  let seconds = 00;
  let tens = 00;
  let minutes = 00;
  let appendSeconds = $("#seconds");
  let appendMinutes = $("#minutes");
  let showSeconds = "00";
  let showMinutes = "00";
  let Interval;


  //on page load
  createBoard();






  //EVENT TRIGGERS
  //when clicking the undo icon reload the page
  $(document).on('click', '.fa-undo', function() {
    location.reload();
  });


  $('.card').click(function(event) {

    //if this is the initial click, start the stopwatch

    if (attempts === 0) {
      startWatch();
    };


    //flip the card if it isn't already open or the comparison array full

    if ($(this).hasClass("flipped") || $(this).hasClass("solved") || comparisonArray.length >= 2) {

      return;

    } else {

      flipCard($(event.target).parent());
    };

    //open the card and store the card information in an array

    comparisonArray.push($(this).data("card-type"));

    //if this is the first card clicked simply count the click and number of attempts

    if (clickCount === 0) {

      clickCount++;
      recordAttempts();

    } else {

      //if this is the second card clicked compare whether it is the same as the other stored card. If yes, add to the number of pairs and change the css attribute to permanently leave the card open.

      if (comparisonArray[0] === comparisonArray[1]) {


        $("[data-card-type=" + comparisonArray[0] + "]").removeClass('flipped').addClass('solved');

        $("[data-card-type=" + comparisonArray[0] + "]").parent().addClass('animated pulse');

        pairs++;

        if (pairs === 8) {
          gameOver();
        }
      };

      //close all unsuccessfully opened cards and clear the comparison array with a short delay

      setTimeout(function() {
        flipCard($('.flipped'));
        comparisonArray = [];

      }, 1000);

      //reset the click count

      clickCount = 0;

    }

  });




  //FUNCTIONS

  //function to flip cards
  function flipCard(element) {
    $(element).toggleClass('flipped');

  }

  //function to record the number of attempts of a player and to reduce the number of stars based on performance
  function recordAttempts() {
    attempts++;
    $('#attempts').html(attempts);

    if (attempts > 16 && attempts < 24) {
      stars = '<i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i>';
      $('#stars').html(stars);
    } else if (attempts >= 24 && attempts < 32) {
      stars = '<i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i>';
      $('#stars').html(stars);
    } else if (attempts >= 32) {
      stars = '<i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i>';
      $('#stars').html(stars);
    } else {
      return;
    };

  }

  //function to create the memory board
  function createBoard() {

    cardArray = shuffle(cardArray);
    memoryBoard.html('');
    for (i = 1; i <= cardArray.length; i++) {
      memoryBoard.append($(`<div class='container'><div class='card' data-card-type='${cardArray[i-1]}'><figure class='front'></figure><figure class='back'></figure></div></div>'`));
    }
  };


  //function for what happens when all pairs are found and the game is over
  function gameOver() {
    stopWatch();

    $('.container').addClass('animated infinite rotateIn');

    messageWinning();
  }

  //function for the popup message on winning
  function messageWinning() {

    $(`<section class="game-over"><div class="message-box"><div class="close-popup">Close</div><h2>Yay! You have found all pairs!</h2><p>Number of attempts: ${attempts}</p><p>Time required: ${showMinutes}:${showSeconds} </p><p>Level: ${stars} </p><p><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></p></div></section>`).insertAfter($('.game'));

    $('.message-box').fadeIn(1000);

  }


  // shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }


  //Stopwatch function, based on https://www.cssscript.com/a-minimal-pure-javascript-stopwatch/

  function stopWatch() {
    clearInterval(Interval);
  }

  function startWatch() {

    clearInterval(Interval);
    Interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);

    function startTimer() {
      tens++;

      if (tens > 99) {
        seconds++;
        showSeconds = "0" + seconds;
        appendSeconds.html(showSeconds);
        tens = 0;
      }

      if (seconds > 9) {
        showSeconds = seconds;
        appendSeconds.html(showSeconds);
      }

      if (seconds > 59) {
        minutes++;
        showMinutes = "0" + minutes;
        appendMinutes.html(showMinutes);
        seconds = 0;
        showSeconds = "0" + 0;
        appendSeconds.html(showSeconds);
      }

      if (minutes > 9) {
        showMinutes = minutes;
        appendMinutes.html(showMinutes);
      }

    }


  }

  $(document).on('click', '.close-popup', function() {
    $('.message-box').hide().parent().removeClass('game-over');
    createBoard();
  });

});
```

```css
/* ...............................
GLOBAL SETTINGS
.................................*/


/* COLOR PALETTE
credit to http://colorpalettes.net/color-palette-1298/
#a6d5e5
#85c3b4
#fbed60
#96bce9
#ddcfe8
*/

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 300%;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 5% 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-star {
  color: #fbed60;
}

p {
  margin: 1%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.fa-undo {
  padding: 0 20% 20% 20%;
}

.message-box .fa-undo {
  padding: 10%;
}

.fa-undo:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* ...............................
GENERAL PAGE LAYOUT
.................................*/

header::before,
footer::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  background: #fbed60;
  height: 20px;
}

header {
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffff92;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

footer {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

footer div {
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* ...............................
SPECIFIC SETTINGS
.................................*/

.game {
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* STATISTICS */

.stats {
  margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
}

ul.stats {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

ul.stats li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 25%;
}


/* CARDBOARD */


/* card with equal height and width on resizing , credit to http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html/ */

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}


/*card flip effect, credit to https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html */

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card figure:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.front {
  background-color: #85c3b4;
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.flipped,
.card.solved {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}


/* Card Backgrounds */

[data-card-type="A"] .back {
  background: #f5f5f5 url('https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg');
}

[data-card-type="B"] .back {
  background: #f5f5f5 url('https://via.placeholder.com/151.jpg');
}

[data-card-type="C"] .back {
  background: #f5f5f5 url('https://via.placeholder.com/152.jpg');
}

[data-card-type="D"] .back {
  background: #f5f5f5 url('https://via.placeholder.com/153.jpg');
}

[data-card-type="E"] .back {
  background: #f5f5f5 url('https://via.placeholder.com/154.jpg');
}

[data-card-type="F"] .back {
  background: #f5f5f5 url('https://via.placeholder.com/155.jpg');
}

[data-card-type="G"] .back {
  background: #f5f5f5 url('https://via.placeholder.com/156.jpg');
}

[data-card-type="H"] .back {
  background: #f5f5f5 url('https://via.placeholder.com/157.jpg');
}


/* POPUP MESSAGE ON WINNING */

.game-over {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.message-box {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 5%;
  border: 5px solid #fbed60;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.message-box {
  position: relative;
}

.close-popup {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Memory Card Game</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Memory Card Game</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="game">
      <ul class="stats">
        <li id="stars"><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
        <li>
          <p>Attempts</p>
          <p id="attempts">0</p>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-hourglass-start"></i>
          <p><span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span></p>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="memory-game">

      </div>

    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div>Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/smashicons" title="Smashicons">Smashicons</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> are licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/"
        title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div>

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This has been extremely helpful, thank you very much for this! I'm a beginner with HTML/CSS/JS so was struggling to figure out what pieces to put in where. Thank you!